# How to install homebrew packages locally

Tags: admin, homebrew

I got homebrew installed, however I do not have admin access. How do I install homebrew packages without admin access? Is there a local tag or something that I keep missing?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Homebrew needs `/usr/local` to be `chown`-ed to your user, and you need `sudo` for that. If you can’t you have to install it elsewhere. Some people use `~/.brew` or `~/homebrew`; you can use anything but avoid paths with spaces. [See the docs here](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/Installation.md#alternative-installs).

Let’s say you want to install in `~/.brew`; run the following command:

```
git clone --depth=1 https://github.com/Homebrew/brew ~/.brew
```

Then ensure the `bin` and `sbin` directories are in your `PATH`. If you’re using Bash add the following in your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.brew/bin:$HOME/.brew/sbin:$PATH"
```

Run `source ~/.bash_profile` or restart your shell and run `brew doctor` to see if it’s installed correctly. It should warn you it’s not installed into `/usr/local` but that’s expected here.

Comment: I just want to add that, to make this work I had to run `brew update` first!

Comment: We ran this when the current version of brew was 2.1.4. These instructions yielded brew v1.7.x, which we easily `brew upgrade`d immediately. No sudo required! We did have to manually add the location of brew to the `PATH`, which is not mentioned).

Comment: Currently, the docs provided for [homebrew (legacy)](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Installation.md#alternative-installs) is now outdated. ([last commit](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/blob/15f291ddaa05cc010456a733b799382175c29dd4/share/doc/homebrew/Installation.md#alternative-installs))
See the new [updated link](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/docs/Installation.md#alternative-installs) ([commit](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/3f64bcb2fbffc663be53b1739c1e6009be9db055/docs/Installation.md#alternative-installs))

Answer (score 1):

To install **homebrew without sudo**.

```
git clone https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew.git
echo 'export PATH="/path/to/cloned_folder/homebrew/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

> Update the `/path/to/cloned_folder` with the path of the **homebrew** cloned folder.

**Restart terminal** and run

```
brew update
brew --version
```

Comment: Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo.

Comment: But running OSX as the root user gets things moving, such as viewing and agreeing to the software licence.

Comment: What should I use for "/path/to/cloned_folder"?

Comment: @WilliamK, folder path is where you have done the git clone of hombrew. I mean that much you have think from your side.

Answer (score 1):

```
 git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/brew

 pwd

 echo 'export PATH="*RESULT_OF_PWD*/brew/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 0):

if it's for programming/building purposes you could also is easy to download the formula, extract the download url, and unzip it in your prefix (is your local folder): it's json https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula/gtk+3.json